# Making a simple invoice web app with Spring but which technologies is advisable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I am going to teach myself some Java EE and making a simple web portal where people can generate their own invoices(pdf lib is needed). Not asking about any code but can you give advice (*examples*) which technologies I can make use of through the process? I have decided to use "**Spring MVC**"   as the framework + java/Kotlin as a compiler. Some database + server + email+ some micro services?, are needed but which can it be? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am there here are my choices. All these choices are based on my past 4 complete end to end web application project experience.

**Spring Boot**
 Using spring boot create micro services. As it has in built tomcat it will be easy to deploy any environment, either local laptop or on premise server or cloud server.

**JPA with Hibernate**
If you are looking for free you can choose MYSQL. As it has strong community support 
 almost all the issues you are going to face would have been asked and answered already under stack overflow or somewhere else in the internet. Another think is as you chose JPA you can switch to any database easily.

**React**
As of now the simplest and one of the fastest ui framework. Also it has strong user support. You can find answer to almost all questions you will have on internet.

Apart from all, you can extend any of these technologies. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you very much, Rajesh. What are you suggesting about the micro-services (a kind decentralizing architecture) Should I start with this architecture in mind from the start and adapt everything to it?

Comment: Yes, you can start with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to implement microservices, i prefer spring boot which has embedded tomcat with additional services, and for database you can use open source mysql
if you are also planning for UI stuff and new to it prefer basic Html,css and Bootstrap

Comment: thanks, does this mean I can get the same functionality as in Spring MVC when using Spring boot? or Spring MVC is a subset of the Spring boot. I do not fully understand if I need the microservices but I have read they are important!

Comment: okay, first lets know the difference between spring boot and spring MVC, MVC is a design pattern and more over an architecture, so if you want to create an application with UI interaction layer then MVC is good approach. If you want to create a simple microservice the Spring boot is recommended. In straight to your question you can get spring MVC functionality using spring boot, it's all depends on requirement, find example here  https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Spring MVC does not mean a specific edition of Spring optimized for MVC but a way to use Spring to conform to this design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using Jaspersoft for generating your pdf files:

https://www.jaspersoft.com/reporting-software

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/introduction-jaspersoft-studio

There may undoubtedly be other solutions out there, but this is the one I'm most used to.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at the "price politics" for JasperSoft without being wiser. Is it a expensive product in your eyes?

Comment: @RolfEilertJohansen there are parts of Jasper you can use without having to pay anything. If you're managing your libraries and dependencies using maven you can download the jasperreports library to make use of it. You can then use JasperSoft Studio to design the report structure/layout.